# Is it possible to install multiple AppCode versions side by side

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide, appcode, app-code

I am a huge fan of Jetbrains "AppCode". But due to the variety of projects I have some depending on older XCode versions and others can be the latest and greatest. It's great that we can have multiple XCode installations side-by-side. But is this also possible with AppCode? I remember that back a couple of years, the EAP version could be installed side-by-side with the stable release. This would also already help, but I cant even find a separate EAP download anymore.

Anybody any tips for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [JetBrains Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/app/) to install as many product versions as you like side by side with the automatic update (optional) and rollback support.

In Toolbox you can set certain product versions to stick to the specific installed version and do not offer the updates.

Major IDE versions do not share the configuration and can be even run at the same time. Minor version can be also configured to use different folders for config/plugins/caches if needed.

Comment: Generally a good idea. I have just tried it out, but is it possible to install the "latest" AppCode twice? Or just different versions side by side?

Comment: Yes, you can install the same version several times. Use Install Again option on the right of the available product if you already have one version installed. In Toolbox Settings | Configuration per product you can change the config/plugins/system directories for each product instance so that several instances of the same version can be used at the same time.